# How to combine lapply with dplyr in a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lapply, plyr

Below is a sample data frame that I have created along with the expected output.

```
df = data.frame(color = c("Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Magenta"),
                values = c(24, 24, 34, 45, 49),
                Quarter = c("Period1","Period2" , "Period3", "Period3", "Period1"),
                Market = c("Camden", "StreetA", "DansFireplace", "StreetA", "DansFireplace"))


dfXQuarter = df %>% group_by(Quarter) %>% summarise(values = sum(values)) %>%
  mutate(cut = "Quarter") %>% data.frame()

colnames(dfXQuarter)[1] = "Grouping"

dfXMarket = df %>% group_by(Market) %>% summarise(values = sum(values)) %>% 
  mutate(cut = "Market")%>% data.frame()
colnames(dfXMarket)[1] = "Grouping"


df_all = rbind(dfXQuarter, dfXMarket)
```

Now I for the sake brevity I want to compile this into a function and using lapply.
Below is my attempt at the same-

```
list = c("Market", "Quarter")


df_all <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, function(x){
  df_l= df %>% group_by(x) %>% 
    summarise(values = sum(values)) %>% 
    mutate(cut= x) %>% 
    data.frame()
   colnames(df_l)[df_l$x] = "Grouping"
  df_l
}))
```

This block of code is giving me error.

I need the output to be the exact replica of the 'df_all' output for further operations.

How I do write this function correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `purrr::map_dfr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) 
#Don't use the R build-in type e.g. list in variables name 
lst <- c("Market", "Quarter")
#Use map if you need the output as a list
map_dfr(lst, ~df %>% group_by("Grouping"=!!sym(.x)) %>% 
                                   summarise(values = sum(values)) %>%
                                   mutate(cut = .x) %>% 
                                   #To avoid the warning massage from bind_rows
                                   mutate_if(is.factor, as.character))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Grouping      values cut    
  <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  
1 Camden            24 Market 
2 DansFireplace     83 Market 
3 StreetA           69 Market 
4 Period1           73 Quarter
5 Period2           24 Quarter
6 Period3           79 Quarter
```

We can fix the first solution by

1. change `group_by(x)` to `group_by_at(x)`, since x is a string here.
2. Use `colnames(df_l)[colnames(df_l)==x] <- "Grouping"` in naming the grouping variable.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty but works and doesn't require tidy functions:

```
groupwise_summation <- function(df, grouping_vecs){


  # Split, apply, combine: 

  tmpdf <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df[,grouping_vecs]), function(x){sum(x$values)}))

  # Clean up the df: 

  data.frame(cbind(cut = row.names(tmpdf), value = as.numeric(tmpdf)), row.names = NULL)


}


# Apply and combine:

df_all <- rbind(groupwise_summation(df, c("Quarter")), groupwise_summation(df, c("Market")))


# Note inside the c(), you can use multiple grouping variables.
```

Comment: Also I need to use tidy syntax since this is just a snippet of the data. The actual dataframe consists of many variables and hence tidyverse syntax would be more efficient.

Comment: Also I need the 'cut' and 'grouping' column as demonstrated in the result of the first block of the code for further operations. I need the output to be the exact replica of the 'df_all' output for further operations.

Comment: @Manasi "The actual dataframe consists of many variables and hence tidyverse syntax would be more efficient" I generally find the opposite to be true. Why do you want to explicitly define a function if you only need that exact output ?

Comment: I needed to define a function because in my vector 'list' I have many variables. For example i needed to group for "Quarter", "Market", "Color", "Tag" etc. writing a function would enable me to execute them all in one go instead of 'groupwise_summation' for each variable. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try the edited version of my code above. I think you will find it functions exactly as you requested.